# Read nupkg package info at runtime

Tags: c#, .net, .net-standard

At runtime, I'd like to read and use the current package's `PackageId` that's defined in `*.csproj` (e.g. for displaying the current version in the program).

Is there a way of doing that?

Comment: At runtime, there's no such thing as a package. There are only assemblies. There's plenty of questions on how to read the version information from assemblies.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This information is not available at run time.

You need to add it yourself at compile time. One option would be to embed package.config and read it at run-rime. If you need exact list as defined in project you have to read csproj at compile time and generate info to put into solution.

Note that for some cases you may use assembly version to report similar information, but there is no guarantee that assembly version matches or even relates to package version and may stay the same forever for some packages .